# How to use Sparse Vector Feature with Numerical Feature correctly in pandas to train sklearn model?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I create Bag-Of-Word Feature

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,5))
all_corpus = X_train["excerpt"].append(X_val["excerpt"]).append(df_test["excerpt"])
vectorizer.fit(all_corpus)
bag_of_word_feature = vectorizer.transform(X_train["excerpt"])
X_train["count_bag_of_word_feature"] = bag_of_word_feature
```

I also create numerical feature (each feature is a number)

```
X_train["avg_sent_length"] = X_train["sent_tokenize"].apply(calculate_avg_sentences_length)
X_val["avg_sent_length"] = X_val["sent_tokenize"].apply(calculate_avg_sentences_length)
```

Here is my dataframe.

[image]

It does not work when I try to fit the model:

```
regressor = KNeighborsRegressor(10, weights='distance')
regressor.fit(X_train_feature, y_train.to_numpy())
```

It will work if I use either numerical feature

```
regressor1.fit(X_train_feature[["avg_word_length", "avg_sent_length"]], y_train.to_numpy())
```

or Bag-of-word feature

```
regressor2.fit(bag_of_word_feature , y_train.to_numpy())
```

How to join all three features above correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

The output from `vectorizer.transform()` is a sparse matrix and you cannot just force it into a column in a pandas dataframe. You can convert it to dense, using `bag_of_word_feature.toarray()` and concatenate it to your data frame, but maybe not advisable if your data is huge.

Below I use some example data:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, hstack

twenty_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train',categories=['sci.med','comp.graphics'])

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit(twenty_train.data)
bag_of_word_feature = vectorizer.transform(twenty_train.data)
```

Lets say we have two other numerical features in a dataframe:

```
avg_train = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(len(twenty_train.data),2)),
             columns=["avg_word_length", "avg_sent_length"])
```

We just need to convert these into sparse, and hstack them:

```
X_train = hstack([csr_matrix(avg.values),bag_of_word_feature])
y_train = twenty_train.target
regressor = KNeighborsRegressor(10, weights='distance')
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: thank buddy, I will try and get back to you soon